# Pandas - get all cases of more than one distinct value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Doing my 1st steps on Python 3.7.7. I got this panda dataframe (df):

```
date    hour    username    devicename
24/04/2020  09:00:00    AA  PC1
24/04/2020  10:00:00    AA  PC1
24/04/2020  09:30:00    BB  PC2
24/04/2020  09:35:00    BB  PC1
24/04/2020  15:00:00    CC  PC1
25/04/2020  09:00:00    AA  PC1
25/04/2020  09:10:00    BB  PC1
25/04/2020  09:15:00    BB  PC2
25/04/2020  10:00:00    BB  PC3
26/04/2020  09:00:00    AA  PC1
26/04/2020  09:15:00    AA  PC2
26/04/2020  12:00:15    AA  PC1
26/04/2020  10:30:00    BB  PC1
26/04/2020  17:15:00    BB  PC1
26/04/2020  15:05:00    CC  PC1
26/04/2020  16:30:00    CC  PC2
```

I want to get all the cases that an user login on more than 1 'devicename' in the same day. So the result that I expect is:

```
date    hour    username    devicename
24/04/2020  09:30:00    BB  PC2
24/04/2020  09:35:00    BB  PC1
25/04/2020  09:10:00    BB  PC1
25/04/2020  09:15:00    BB  PC2
25/04/2020  10:00:00    BB  PC3
26/04/2020  09:00:00    AA  PC1
26/04/2020  09:15:00    AA  PC2
26/04/2020  12:00:15    AA  PC1
26/04/2020  15:05:00    CC  PC1
26/04/2020  16:30:00    CC  PC2
```

So far I got:

```
df[df['devicename'].notnull()].groupby(['username','date'])['devicename'].nunique()

username    date    devicename
BB  25/04/2020  3
AA  26/04/2020  2
BB  24/04/2020  2
CC  26/04/2020  2
AA  24/04/2020  1
AA  25/04/2020  1
BB  26/04/2020  1
CC  24/04/2020  1
```

Hope anyone can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with compare greater like `1` by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html):

```
df = df[df.groupby(['username','date'])['devicename'].transform('nunique').gt(1)]

print (df)
          date      hour username devicename
2   24/04/2020  09:30:00       BB        PC2
3   24/04/2020  09:35:00       BB        PC1
6   25/04/2020  09:10:00       BB        PC1
7   25/04/2020  09:15:00       BB        PC2
8   25/04/2020  10:00:00       BB        PC3
9   26/04/2020  09:00:00       AA        PC1
10  26/04/2020  09:15:00       AA        PC2
11  26/04/2020  12:00:15       AA        PC1
14  26/04/2020  15:05:00       CC        PC1
15  26/04/2020  16:30:00       CC        PC2
```